# ViewModel in Model - legal implementation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**SHORT**

When it comes to MVVM, is it legal to have a ViewModel in a Model class due to polymorphism?

---

**DETAILED**

Imagine you have the following construct of 2 classes:

```
public class ArticleModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionModel
{
    public ArticleModel ArticleModel { get; set; }
}
```

So basically every transaction has an associated article. Therefore, if you wrap this in a ViewModel, it may look as follows:

ArticleViewModel

```
public class ArticleModelView
{
    private ArticleModel _ArticleModel;
    public ArticleModel ArticleModel
    {
        // basic get and set + notify
    }

    public string Name
    {
        // basic get and set + notify
    }
}
```

TransactionViewModel

```
public class TransactionViewModel
{
    private TransactionModel _TransactionModel;
    public TransactionModel TransactionModel
    {
        // basic get and set + notify
    }

    public ArticleModel ArticleModel
    {
        // basic get and set + notify
    }
}
```

The reason I'm asking is, if you declare a `TransactionViewModel` with a `TransactionModel`, you won't get the updates of the underlying `ArticleModel`. For example:

```
TransactionViewModel transactionViewModel = new TransactionViewModel
(new TransactionModel(new ArticleModel("sometestname")));
```

Now, when changing the name of the underlying `ArticleModel`:

```
transactionViewModel.ArticleModel.Name = "hi";
```

nothing will be notified of the changes made since I did not assign a new `ArticleModel` but instead just changed the name attribute.

If the `ArticleModel` property in `TransactionModel` would be an `ArticleViewModel`, the changes would have been reported. I could even implement a `ArticleViewModel` in the `TransactionViewModel` but then there could be still the chance that due to wrong access the changes may not be reported.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I've never heard of anyone putting a view model inside a model. If anything you would have your model within your viewmodel. Technically though, its not true MVVM to bind your Model to your view. So to get around this, in your viewmodel, you would have view model properties that match your model. Then you can map them on save. If you must use the model, then I would implement INotifyPropertyChange on your properties in your model, else do it on you view model properties

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you are trying to change the articlemodels name property but also notifyproperty change, which the way you are doing it won't work unless your model implements the inotifypropertychange. What you could do is somehting like:

```
    public class TransactionViewModel
    {
        public ArticleModel CurrentArticleModel { get; set; }

        public String Name 
        {
            get { return CurrentArticleModel.Name; }

            set 
            {
                CurrentArticleModel.Name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange("Name");
            }
    }
```

Also if necessary, I don't see anything wrong with your TransactionViewModel having an instance of a ArticleViewModel. I would assume that the ArticleViewModel would be bound to its own usercontrol or something though

Comment: Having `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented in the Model is not what I want. I'm aware of the fact, that I simply could do this but in my opinion, this is, however, not a valid MVVM architecture. And yes, implementing `ArticleViewModel` would eliminate the problem but there would be still 2 possible ways to access the underlying `ArticleModel` while one is not notifying.

Comment: @Mostey, what\`s wrong with Model notifiying about property changes? And on top of that, how\`s that breaking MVVM?

Comment: @icebat The ViewModel notifies, not the Model. That being said, polluting my Model with ViewModel related stuff is no option for me. You can do that but in my opinion, this is against the rules of the pattern.

Comment: @Mostey, change notification is not bound to MVVM and can be used for many reasons. RIA Services [Entity type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.entity%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) has change notification, for example. I don\`t see nothing wrong with using it in your scenario.

Comment: @icebat Indeed, it is not bound to MVVM but that doesn't change the fact that it is not appropriate to implement the interface in a model when we are talking about MVVM. As stated above, I also don't want to pollute my Model with notification stuff.